# expressjs - response body not set

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

In the following NodeJS API, a PostgreSQL database is inserted with multiple rows and then a response body needs to be sent. Since there are multiple scenarios where there could be an error, I need to set-up response body with a message code that helps identify a possible cause. Therefore, I am using a `resp` object that will hold a `code` key for a message code. This object will be sent in a HTTP response where the status is either `200` (success) or `500` (error).

However, I keep getting an empty response body. Is the variable scope ok?

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  rdbmsPool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
      var resp = {
        'Request-Id' : req.get('X-Request-Id'),
        'code' : 'code'
      }
      res.status(500)
      res.send(resp)
    } else {
      var resp = {}
      for (k in someArray) {

          client.query(queryString, colValues, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              resp = {
                'Request-Id' : req.get('X-Request-Id'),
                'code' : 'code'
              }
              res.status(500)
            } else {
              resp = {
                'Request-Id' : req.get('X-Request-Id'),
                'code' : 'code'
              }
              res.status(200)       
            }
          })
        }
      for (k in someOtherArray) {
          client.query(queryString, colValues, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              resp = {
                'Request-Id' : req.get('X-Request-Id'),
                'code' : 'code'
              }
              res.status(500)
            } else {
              resp = {
                'Request-Id' : req.get('X-Request-Id'),
                'code' : 'code'
              }
              res.status(200)       
            }
          })
        }
    release()
    res.send(resp)        
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
let array1 = [];
for(k in someArray){
    array1.push(client.query(queryString, colValues));
}

let array2 = [];

for (k in someOtherArray) {
    array2.push(client.query(queryString, colValues));
}

try{
    const results1 = await Promise.all(array1);
    const results2 = await Promise.all(array2);
    // if it comes here queries are successful
}
catch(error){
    //send 500 here. any query have failed
    console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is your response is sent before queries are completed. Your query execution is asynchronous and `res.send(resp)`  does not wait until queries are executed.

The variable `resp` is set inside callbacks therefore it is empty.

You can try using async-await for synchronized execution with promise wrapper for parrelel execution of queries that are run inside loop. Note `async function`.

This is how it can be done with node mysql2/promise. Asynchronous means that the callback function you provide in query() will be called after query is executed. and the code after query() will run not waiting until query function is completed.

```
router.get('/getDayTypes',async function (req, res, next) {
    const API_NAME='getDayTypes get, ';

    try{
        const conn = await pool.getConnection();
            // Do something with the connection
        var promise1 = conn.execute(`
        SELECT 
            ID_DAY_TYPES,
            DAY_NAME
        FROM
            hrm_calendar_day_types 
        WHERE
            IS_ACTIVE = '1'`);


        const values = await Promise.all([promise1]);
        conn.release();

        return res.status(200).send({success:true, data:values[0][0]});
    }

    catch(err){
        logger.error(API_NAME + 'error :' + err);
        return res.status(500).send({success:false, message:'Query Error'});
    }
});
```

Comment: 'Your query execution is asynchronous' - how? `await client.query` does not work. I get this error message - `await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Thanks. How are you getting the `pool` variable? I am using https://node-postgres.com/ BTW, mine are `INSERT` statements where, each `POST` could lead to potentially a dozen inserts across 3-4 tables.

Comment: `const result = await client.query(queryString, colValues);` will be enough according to the library.

Comment: checkout my other answer. I think you can keep using same connection for promises.

Comment: How do I capture the `err` object also in `await`? Since my statements are `INSERT`s, I need to know, if there was a 'duplicate on insert' error. `try {} catch (e) {}`?

Comment: Yes . Inside catch block

Comment: await client.query does not work. I get this error message - await is only valid in async function

Comment: You should put `async` before `function(req,res)`. `async` works only inside functions that are marked as async.